# custom header navigation has odd spacing

Tags: css, navigation, html, headers

[Live site.](http://urbanpalate.com/blog/)

I'm using a custom header on my blog page which features the same coding as my regular heading for `nav`.
The `nav` looks fine on all pages but the blog page- the Blog button shifts left. 
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's causing the causation of your problem, but for some reason the `<li>` tags are not being added around the "portfolio" menu item, when you visit the blog page. Maybe you can see why in the custom header menu code?!

The `<li>` tags are what creates the spacing(padding-right) in between each menu item, so without them on the portfolio item, the blog menu item shifts to the left.

Comment: Beat me to it lol

Comment: Of course it was something so easy :/ Thank you!